# Using self in a Swift closure with SIOSocket

Tags: objective-c, swift, websocket, closures, self

I am hoping someone can help me. I trying to use SIOSocket with a Swift project.

I am using the example at https://github.com/MegaBits/SIOSocket/issues/30 which seems to work, but i want to be able to declare a `socket` as a `var` like the Objective-C project example at https://github.com/MegaBits/WorldPin. so i can use it in else where in the code to call emit.

I assume i am not understanding the Obj-C block and Swift closure fundamentals and the use of `self` or the need to declare the `var` as block but can’t seem to wrap my head around it. Any help will be much appreciated.

[SIOSocket is on Github](https://github.com/MegaBits/SIOSocket)

Objective-C code:

```
    @property SIOSocket *socket;

    [SIOSocket socketWithHost: @"http://localhost:3000" response: ^(SIOSocket *socket)
{
    self.socket = socket; //I Want to do this in swift

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    self.socket.onConnect = ^()
    {
        weakSelf.socketIsConnected = YES;
        [weakSelf mapView: weakSelf.mapView didUpdateUserLocation: weakSelf.mapView.userLocation];
    };

    [self.socket on: @"join" callback: ^(SIOParameterArray *args)
    {
        [weakSelf mapView: weakSelf.mapView didUpdateUserLocation: weakSelf.mapView.userLocation];
    }];

    [self.socket on: @"update" callback: ^(SIOParameterArray *args)
    {
        NSString *pinData = [args firstObject];
```

etc etc …

Swift Code:

```
private func connectToHost() {
    SIOSocket.socketWithHost(host, reconnectAutomatically: true, attemptLimit: 0, withDelay: 1, maximumDelay: 5, timeout: 20, response: {
        socket in

            self.socket = socket // This gives me a use of unresolved identifier self error

            socket.onConnect = {
                println("Connected to \(host)")
                socket.emit("add user", args: [username])
            }

            socket.on("login", callback: {(AnyObject data) -> Void in
                println(["login": data])
                socket.emit("new message", args: [message])
            })

            socket.onDisconnect = {
                println("Disconnected from \(host)")
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work, make sure you have all the right types and optional types, make sure socket is a `read-write` variable by defining it with `var` and not with `let`.

Try defining the closure before the method call by using `let response: (SIOSocket) -> Void = {...}`.

Comment: Actually - i am an idiot i had the function outside the class. Figures first question i actually decide i need to ask was my mistake.. Thanks!

Comment: Most of the times I say "Well Swift is in beta, the error reporting is going to improve", but this time it was spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
 SIOSocket.socketWithHost(host, reconnectAutomatically: true, attemptLimit: 0, withDelay: 1, maximumDelay: 5, timeout: 20, response: {(socket: SIOSocket) in

     self.socket = socket // This gives me a use of unresolved identifier self error

    //...
})
```

I changed `socket in` to `(socket: SIOSocket) in`

Comment: Actually -  i am an idiot i had the function outside the class.  Figures first question i actually decide i need to ask was my mistake..

Comment: I really appreciate the quick response though!